# Know when "audio" tag html has been play

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm using audio tags, what I want it's to count how many times has been played.

My code it's like this:

```
<audio id="sound" controls="controls" onplaying="doing(this.id)">;
    <source src="path/filename" type="audio/wav/">; 
</audio>; 
<input type="text" id="numbers" value= "0" >
```

Then in a javascript file

```
Var n=0;
function doing(onplaying)
{
    n = n+1;
    document.getElementById("numbers").value =  n;
}
```

But it does not work, does someone know how to do this, like this or in a different way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that in HTML you don't need to separate lines of code with `;` - those `;`s will actually appear as text.

Comment: How does it not work? does it throw an error you can see in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `play` event, not `playing`: http://jsfiddle.net/a84rC/.

```
document.getElementById("sound").addEventListener('play', doing); // bind event

var n = 0;

function doing() {
    n++; // increase (this is a shortcut to n = n + 1)
    document.getElementById("numbers").value = n;
}
```